# И еще о пасте

Tags: значение-слов

Почитал очень интересную дискуссию об итальянской пасте. Но сразу возник вопрос: а какая связь между итальянским словом "паста" в значении "макаронные изделия" и тем, что подразумеваем под пастой мы: пюре или зубная паста?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Судя по всему - прямая.
Паста - от позделатинского pasta = тесто.
Всякая паста по сути является тестом в широком понимании - твердая основа, разведенная водой до вязкого или тестообразного состояния.
Тем более понятно, что и итальянское слово из той же латыни и даже означает то же тесто. 
Так что родство понятно и объяснимо.